# QR Code Analytics API

Tags: qr-code, web-analytics

Is there a good API or other possible solution to the following?

I am trying to track club membership and discrete "check in" events/activities using QR codes.  First I generate a QR code with an embedded URL to a web page with member information (random/obscured URLs with shortened links) and print that QR code on a label and attach it to a membership card.  I then scan the QR code with Red Laser or some other reader to access the shortened URL and the "hidden" member information.

My issue is that I have 100s (eventually thousands) of QR codes to track so I'm looking for a simple tool or API to manage all of these obscure links and see how often they have been accessed by Red Laser (or a browser if someone manages to discover any of these obscured links).

I tried Google Analytics but I wasn't able to get the level of "fine tune" control I'd like.  What I really want is the ability to map this information (e.g., member contact info, obscure links, number of times clicked, etc.) to a format like chartbeat.com.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Just a hint.  Keep in mind that a QR Code does not have to encode a URL: the information can instead be an arbitrary sequence of letters and numbers (your goal seems to be to make "obscure links")